# How to include a Welcome popup window within Yammer

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to include in Yammer a "Welcome message" window every time an user acccess his yammer account? How can I do that? Could you provide any code examples?

Thanks,
FC

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. 
There is a usage policy feature that can be used to display a message that you can require users to accept. It is documented here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Setting-up-your-Yammer-network-Yammer-admin-guide-f886e916-fe64-41de-be52-38d458250fa5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Not sure if that helps your use case out.